# Prove that if a graph is k-connected, then it is also k-edge-connected

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Here is my thought, first if it is k-connected, then every vertex has degree at least k. So removing a set of size k-1 edges will not result any isolated vertices. I don't know how to continue.

Comment: What can you say about the result of removing $k-1$ edges, compared to the result of removing one endpoint of each of the $k-1$ edges?

Comment: wait I might got this

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).